# To prove the existence of a constant $c$ in a function

Tags: functions

Let $f: R \to R$ be a continuous function.Suppose $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t} (f(x+y)-f(y))dy$$
for all $x \in R $ and $t>0$. Then show that there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x$

At first I want to ask how shall I integrate the function give above? And also how am I supposed to prove the relationship of $f(x)$ with constant $c$ for all value of $x$

Comment: Do you know Newton-Leibinitz's Rule?

Comment: Do you mean Leibinitz's Rule for integration? @JaideepKhare

Comment: Or you can multiply both sides by $t$ and differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: Okay thanks I am gonna try it now. @Michael

Comment: @ItiShree Yes, that's used to take derivatives of multivariable fuction.

Comment: @Michael technically, doing so assumes that $f(x)$ is differentiable, which can be justified but is not explicitly given to us from the problem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : It does not assume that since we are differentiating with respect to $t$. The function $tf(x)$ is linear in $t$.  If Iti Shree can use this suggestion to solve the problem, it would be better if she writes that as an answer.

Comment: @Michael also, I'd say that qualifies as an answer, if you wanted to write one

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why? The LHS is $tf(x)$ and the RHS is $\int_0^tg(y)dy$ for some continuous function $g$.

Comment: @Michael whoops! You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
f(x) = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}f(x+y) - f(y)dy = f(x+t) - f(t)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{t}f(x+y) - f(y)dy = \frac{1}{t}(f(x+t) - f(x)) = f(t)/t
$$
Therefore the derivative is constant.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you got the second equality in your second line, care to explain? Also, how do you know for sure that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: A simple way to earn more respect is to reference related work.  This also holds when writing research papers.  It certainly can't hurt to write something like "Following the suggestion of Michael..." or "similar to the suggestion of..." , and it even promotes a positive and collegial atmosphere.

Comment: @Jason : What Marc is not telling you is that, assuming we can bring the derivative inside the integral and differentiate $f$, then $$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^t [f(x+y)-f(y)]dy = \int_0^t f'(x+y) dy = f(x+t)-f(x)$$ which also assumes we can integrate the derivative. Without making all these assumptions, it is better to just work directly with the first equality and look at rational numbers.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, I realized this soon after my question but since there were missing steps I decided to leave it up (plus, as you also have pointed out, there still is the issue of not justifying differentiability).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Marc, had really hard time understanding the question.