# Suppose $f(x)=\frac 1t\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and all $t>0.$ Then show that $\exists c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb {R}\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose $f(x)=\frac 1t\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy$  for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and all $t>0.$ Then show that $\exists c$  such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x.$

My solution goes like this:

> We have, $f(x)=\frac 1t\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy\implies tf(x)=\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy$  for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and all $t>0.$ We assume, $F(t)=tf(x)$ and $h(y)=f(x+y)-f(y),$ thus, we have, $F(t)=\int_0^th(y)dy.$ From Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus, we have, $F'(t)=h(t)\implies f(x)=f(x+t)-f(t).$ Hence, the function $f$ satisfies $f(x+t)=f(x)+f(t),\forall x\in \Bbb R, t\in \Bbb R^+.$ This is indeed Cauchy's additive functional equation and since, $f$ is continuous everywhere, so the only solution of this functional equation is $f(x)=cx,$ where $c\in\Bbb R.$

Is the above solution valid? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: You can't assume what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @theGrey Can you please elaborate your point  ?

Comment: I think you want to show: f(x+t) = f(x) + f(t) using the equation in the question. Hint: use differentiation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2271678/42969 or  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3549969/42969 for a correct solution.

Comment: @theGrey I have edited my solution. Mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @MartinR I have edited my solution and tried to make it, as less convoluted as I can...Hopefully, this fixes everything!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! I edited my solution and I anticipate this resolves all the issues it had previously.